# Taking more time to fetch records in json object using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have 20000 records, below javascript function taking more time to fetch records in Json object.

```
 $("#txtKey").keyup(function() {
            var value = $("#txtKey").val();
            var exactMatch = $('#exactMatch').is(':checked');
            var key = $("#SearchKey option:selected").val();           
            var filteredData = vLookup(value, data, key, exactMatch);            
            fillTableDataDynamic(filteredData);
        });

  function vLookup(value, data, key, exactMatch) {            
        if (typeof data === "object" && !(data instanceof Array)) {
            var arrData = [];
            arrData.push(data);
            data = arrData;
        }
        var filteredData = [];
        var transValue = value.toLowerCase();

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (exactMatch) {
                if (JSON.stringify(data[i][key]).indexOf(value) > -1) {
                    filteredData.push(data[i]);
                }
            } else {
                if (JSON.stringify(data[i][key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(transValue) > -1) {
                    filteredData.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return filteredData;
    }
```

Any alternate way to fetch record?

Thanks Advance.

Comment: what does a typical record in `data` look like - it's probably the  `JSON.stringify` that's causing the grief

Comment: Its a json, var data = [
    {
        "EmployeeId": 10001,
        "Employee Code": "T44558",
        "First Name": "Cailin",
        "Last Name": "Vaughan",
        "PF Number": "KL/14001/10115"
    },
    {
        "EmployeeId": 10002,
        "Employee Code": "T44559",
        "First Name": "Xerxes",
        "Last Name": "Dorian",
        "PF Number": "KL/14001/10115"
    }];

Comment: it's not **a json** - it's an object - `JSON is a text format that is completely language independent` - http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

from the look of your data

```
        if (exactMatch) {
            if (data[i][key].toString().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                filteredData.push(data[i]);
            }
        } else {
            if (data[i][key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(transValue) > -1) {
                filteredData.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
```

will work for you

so - no speed difference

try this: uses `Array.prototype.filter` - there's extra overhead in the function call, but the `filter` function may yet achieve speed improvement

```
function vLookup(value, data, key, exactMatch) {            
    if (typeof data === "object" && !(data instanceof Array)) {
        var arrData = [];
        arrData.push(data);
        data = arrData;
    }

    var transValue = value.toLowerCase();

    if (exactMatch) {
        return data.filter(function(datum) {
            return datum[key].toString().indexOf(value) > 1;
        });
    } else {
        return data.filter(function(datum) {
            return datum[key].toString().indexOf(transValue) > 1;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No,  TypeError: data[0].EmployeeId.indexOf is not a function.

Comment: Its working fine, but its also take time(no difference). approximately 4 min.

Comment: try the updated code - unfortunately I can't do speed testing for you :D

Comment: Its working now with more speed compared to my code.... Thank you so much @Jaromanda X.